# GCP components update causes "ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused" errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

My GCP deployment was working fine until I did "gcloud components update" two weeks ago. I understand that the command updates the libraries, and there was an option to revert back to the previous version at the end of the update, but I do not understand why there are so many connection-refused errors with the new update. On the client side, I see "502 Bad Gateway errors". These errors are not consistent. I see them occurring 12 times in the last 48 minutes.

```
2018-07-31 09:13:19.000 MST
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw) File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 79, in create_connection raise err File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 69, in create_connection sock.connect(sa) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Expand all | Collapse all
{
 insertId: "crhycg4civkq14"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/eps-server/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2018-07-31T16:13:24.966198879Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
"  
 timestamp: "2018-07-31T16:13:19Z"  
}



2018-07-31 09:13:19.000 MST
AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x7fdd9f316b00>" raised exception!

Expand all | Collapse all
{
 insertId: "crhycg4civkq14"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/eps-server/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2018-07-31T16:13:24.966198879Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 textPayload: "AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x7fdd9f316b00>" raised exception!
"  
 timestamp: "2018-07-31T16:13:19Z"  
}
```

Comment: It seems that your app may be unable to get authentication details from the metadata server. Are you getting this error on every requests or is it intermittent? Which runtime version are you using?

Comment: Even I thought so, but these are intermittent errors. I see about 12 of these errors in 48 Minutes. runtime python: 3.5

Comment: Any update on this?